Set "key" as a value from another type
I have a type like this..

type Table = {
  fieldNames: {
    id: string,
    children?: string
  },
  rows: Array<(
    Record<string, any> & {
      label: string,
      ...
    }
  )>
};

so, when I try to create an object based on this type...
const table: Table = {
  fieldNames: {
    id: "uuid",
    children: "objects"
  },
  rows: [
    {
      label: "test"
    }
  ]
};

"there are no errors" (says Typescript) but we've declared fieldNames.id (uuid) and fieldNames.children (objects) they must be in the object, how to solve it via type?
UPDATE.
 ⬇️ Correct, no errors
const table = {
  fieldNames: {
    id: "uuid", <- - - - - | // "uuid" key must be in a row object
    children: "objects" <- | // "objects" key must be in a row object
  },                       |
  rows: [                  |
    {                      |
      uuid: 1, <- - - - -  | // All is good "uuid" is here
      objects: 2 <- - - -  | // All is good "objects" is here
    }
  ]
};

 ⬇️ Correct, no errors
const table = {
  fieldNames: {
    id: "MY_CUSTOM_ID_KEY", <- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - | // "MY_CUSTOM_ID_KEY" key must be in a row object
    children: "MY_CUSTOM_CHILDREN_KEY" <- - - - - - - - - - - -  | // "MY_CUSTOM_CHILDREN_KEY" key must be in a row object
  },                                                             |
  rows: [                                                        |
    {                                                            |
      MY_CUSTOM_ID_KEY: "SOMETHING VERY GOOD", <- - - - - - - -  | // All is good "MY_CUSTOM_ID_KEY" is here
      MY_CUSTOM_CHILDREN_KEY: "SOMETHING, DO NOT CARE" <- - - -  | // All is good "MY_CUSTOM_CHILDREN_KEY" is here
    }
  ]
};

 ⬇️ Incorrect, "uuid", "objects" missing in row object
const table = {
  fieldNames: {
    id: "uuid", <- - - - - | // "uuid" key must be in a row object
    children: "objects" <- | // "objects" key must be in a row object
  },                       |
  rows: [                  |
    {                      |
      id: 1, <- - - - - -  | // Ok, you can be there but "uuid" is missing
      children: 2 <- - - - | // Ok, you can be there but "objects" is missing
    }
  ]
};

 ➡️ please note the id and children keys do not change, their value changes and these values ​​must be in a row object
 ➡️ I know how to do this via vanilla code (without Typescript), there are no problems here, the question is not about this at all, ➡️ but about Typescript hints ⬅️

Can you edit the question to add an example of the fixed object structure?

@Dogbert done ||

• In your "more examples" it seems you've repeated your previous example again. Is this intentional? Could you fix it? • There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way. If you want this restriction you'll need a generic type and a helper function for inference, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz no, this does not solve my problem, the types should be inferred automatically based on fieldNames, what I mean... in fieldNames there are some keys that are predefined, the value of these keys "points" to a certain key in the row object, which I will refer to in the future, these keys can be absolutely anything... based on the key value from fieldNames Typescript should prompt me to indicate these keys in the row object... since they are not predefined in the row type, because they can be absolutely anything

I don't get it. If you use my playground link you are indeed prompted to indicate those keys in the row object, see this screenshot. In what specific way does my comment not address this issue? Please show me with code, if you can.

@jcalz updated.

Is there any reason your code has pseudocode in it? Those < - - - and | etc require others to comment them out in order to test. Could you provide a [mre] where people don't need to fight with their IDEs to look at it?  There's also semicolons where there shouldn't be, and importantly you're missing label in the "good" example where no errors should appear. It would be great if your code were something people could actually test against.

Please read previous comment and address it.  Keep in mind that there is no specific type in TypeScript that works the way you want, all you can do is have a generic type and a helper function. With that in mind, does this approach, which is more or less the same as my previous suggestion (except I allowed for excess properties) meet your needs? If not, please tell me explicitly why not (because I must be missing it). If so, I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate.

@jcalz there is no specific type in TypeScript that works the way you want alright then,  write your answer I'll accept it

After you added an example you can do like this
create  field names
fieldNames: {
   id: "id value",
   children: "test text"
 }

Then create a table
const table: Table = {
    fieldNames: {
      id: "label",
      children: "field"
    },
    rows: [
    { 
       label: "test",
       field: "value"
   }
          ]
};

you can dynamically access these properties
table.rows.forEach((row) => {
  const children = 
  row[table.fieldNames.children];
     console.log(children);
});


Hi, did you read the question? You just copied my example but separated it by different types :/

Yes i readed it and i edited my response

reread again, I don't need a javascript implementation, I need "typescrtipt to tell me what types I need to specify"

I think you don't fully understand the problem
